# Is there a way to use AutoFac Web Api Authorization Filters through Attributes instead of injection?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, filter, dependency-injection, authorization, autofac

I have an Autofac Web Api Authorization Filter like that:

```
public class MyAuthorizationFilter : IAutofacAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext){}
}

public class MyAuthorizationAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyAuthorizationAttribute() { }
}
```

Right now the only way I can have an Autofac Web Api Authorization Filter is through injecting it in AutofacConfig.cs:

```
builder.RegisterType<MyAuthorizationFilter>()
.AsWebApiAuthorizationFilterFor<MyController>(
    c => c.MyMethod(default(MyModel))
).InstancePerDependency();
```

and it seems the attribute is ignored if I don't inject it as above

```
public MyController : ApiController {

    [MyAuthroziationFilter] // ignored
    [POST("")]
    public HttpResponseMessage MyMethod(MyModel myModel) { 
        [...]
    }
}
```

Is there a way to use attributes/annotations for AutoFac Web Api Authorization Filters instead of injections through AutoFac and also have their dependencies properly injected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you want DI in your filters, you can't use attributes. [Per the docs](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#standard-web-api-filter-attributes-are-singletons):

> Unlike the filter provider in MVC, the one in Web API does not allow you to specify that the filter instances should not be cached. This means that all filter attributes in Web API are effectively singleton instances that exist for the entire lifetime of the application.

If you want to use attributes, the best you can do is use service location inside standard Web API attributes. Get the request lifetime scope off the request message and manually resolve the services you need.

Comment: I was thinking there should be a better way according to this comment: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/autofac/JZViZwr0sNA/C4h67OhMI7UJ (even though they are talking about Action Filters).Btw I had to refactor the old code because the injection of the filters was on all my apicontrollers and the filters were hit for all the requests. Each time there was a check if the apicontroller is decorated with the respective Attribute to filter the correct requests..Now I am injecting on the specific method as I describe in the question. But I feel the code is becoming a list of authorizations...

Comment: Note in the comment it's for MVC. As I mentioned, there's no analogous option in Web API. Trust me, we had a long talk with the ASP.NET guys over this one in the context of ASP.NET 5, trying to tell them to stop over-caching things.

Comment: Ok then thanks :) - I didn't see that you are the co-owner of Autofac :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom extension for ContainerBuilder class of Autofac library:

```cs
public static class ContainerBuilderExtensions
{
    public static void RegisterWebApiFilterAttribute<TAttribute>(this ContainerBuilder builder, Assembly assembly) where TAttribute : Attribute, IAutofacAuthorizationFilter
    {
        Type[] controllerTypes = assembly.GetLoadableTypes()
            .Where(type => typeof(ApiController).IsAssignableFrom(type)).ToArray();
        RegisterFilterForControllers<TAttribute>(builder, controllerTypes);
        RegisterFilterForActions<TAttribute>(builder, controllerTypes);
    }

    // We need to call 
    // builder.RegisterType<TFilter>().AsWebApiAuthorizationFilterFor().InstancePerDependency()
    // for each controller marked with TAttribute
    private static void RegisterFilterForControllers<TAttribute>(ContainerBuilder builder, IEnumerable<Type> controllerTypes) where TAttribute : Attribute, IAutofacAuthorizationFilter
    {
        foreach (Type controllerType in controllerTypes.Where(c => c.GetCustomAttribute<TAttribute>(false)?.GetType() == typeof(TAttribute)))
        {
            GetAsFilterForControllerMethodInfo(controllerType).Invoke(null, new object[] { builder.RegisterType(typeof(TAttribute)) });
        }
    }

    // We need to call 
    // builder.RegisterType<TFilter>().AsWebApiAuthorizationFilterFor(controller => controller.Action(arg)).InstancePerDependency()
    // for each controller action marked with TAttribute
    private static void RegisterFilterForActions<TAttribute>(ContainerBuilder builder, IEnumerable<Type> controllerTypes)
        where TAttribute : Attribute, IAutofacAuthorizationFilter
    {
        foreach (Type controllerType in controllerTypes)
        {
            IEnumerable<MethodInfo> actions = controllerType.GetMethods().Where(method => method.IsPublic && method.IsDefined(typeof(TAttribute)));
            foreach (MethodInfo actionMethodInfo in actions)
            {
                ParameterExpression controllerParameter = Expression.Parameter(controllerType);
                Expression[] actionMethodArgs = GetActionMethodArgs(actionMethodInfo);
                GetAsFilterForActionMethodInfo(controllerType).Invoke(null,
                    new object[] {
                        builder.RegisterType(typeof(TAttribute)),
                        Expression.Lambda(typeof(Action<>).MakeGenericType(controllerType), Expression.Call(controllerParameter, actionMethodInfo, actionMethodArgs),
                            controllerParameter)
                    });
            }
        }
    }

    private static Expression[] GetActionMethodArgs(MethodInfo actionMethodInfo)
    {
        return actionMethodInfo.GetParameters().Select(p => Expression.Constant(GetDefaultValueForType(p.ParameterType), p.ParameterType)).ToArray<Expression>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Returns info for <see cref="Autofac.Integration.WebApi.RegistrationExtensions" />.AsWebApiAuthorizationFilterFor()
    ///     method
    /// </summary>
    private static MethodInfo GetAsFilterForControllerMethodInfo(Type controllerType)
    {
        return GetAsFilterForMethodInfo(controllerType, parametersCount: 1);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Returns info for <see cref="Autofac.Integration.WebApi.RegistrationExtensions" />
    ///     .AsWebApiAuthorizationFilterForerFor(actionSelector) method
    /// </summary>
    private static MethodInfo GetAsFilterForActionMethodInfo(Type controllerType)
    {
        return GetAsFilterForMethodInfo(controllerType, parametersCount: 2);
    }

    private static MethodInfo GetAsFilterForMethodInfo(Type controllerType, int parametersCount)
    {
        return typeof(RegistrationExtensions).GetMethods()
            .Single(m => m.Name == nameof(RegistrationExtensions.AsWebApiAuthorizationFilterFor) && m.GetParameters().Length == parametersCount)
            .MakeGenericMethod(controllerType);
    }

    private static object GetDefaultValueForType(Type t)
    {
        return typeof(ContainerBuilderExtensions).GetMethod(nameof(GetDefaultGeneric))?.MakeGenericMethod(t).Invoke(null, null);
    }

    private static T GetDefaultGeneric<T>()
    {
        return default;
    }
}
```

Then you'll be able to make one registration for the whole assembly, not for each controller:

```cs
public class LoggerFilterAttribute : Attribute, IAutofacAuthorizationFilter
{
    private readonly ILog _logger;
    //if you don't want empty constructor you can use separate "marker" attribute and current class will not have to inherit Attribute, but you will need to modify ContainerBuilderExtensions
    public LoggerFilterAttribute() { }
    public LoggerFilterAttribute(ILog logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.Trace($"Authorizing action '{actionContext.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName}.{actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName}'");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Registration:

```cs
builder.RegisterWebApiFilterAttribute<LoggerFilterAttribute>(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

You can use your attribute on controller or action:

```cs
public class AuthorsController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/authors
    [LoggerFilter]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "author1", "author2" };
    }        
}

[LoggerFilter]
public class BooksController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/books
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "book1", "book2" };
    }
}
```

The whole demo project is on [github](https://github.com/batkaevruslan/AutofacWebApiFilter)